# Deploy Google Cloud Function from GAE/Java

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'd like to deploy a Google Cloud Function from GAE/Java but I cannot find any info about deploying a function other than using the gcloud command line tool.
Is there a way to deploy a cloud function from Google App Engine (standard) / Java e.g. by using the Cloud Storage API and setting some additional fields on the request (e.g. for the httptrigger etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Cloud Functions using the [REST](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.functions/create) or [RPC](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.functions.v1beta2#google.cloud.functions.v1beta2.CreateFunctionRequest) end-points.